# Autohotkey alternative for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, scripting, autohotkey

This question has been asked before but with no answer. I'm running into brick walls with google too. Program can either be free or paid.

Comment: Any ideas? I've tried using automator + terminal, but I am finding that their functions are too limited compared to AutoHotKey.

Comment: If you are looking for Keyboard shortcuts and Key re-mapping and customization only, then free KeyRemap4MacBook is awesome: http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Keymando](http://keymando.com/) - $19, 30-day free trial. Uses Ruby as its scripting language.

IronAHK will run AHK scripts, but for its GUI it requires X11.app. I don't believe it can automate regular Mac apps.

Comment: Keymando has recently moved off the App Store and has been updated.  You can get the new version at http://keymando.com  Let me know if you've already bought it through the App Store and I'll get you a new license.

Comment: A warning: Keymando is very poorly documented. Also, its takes up a LOT of CPU utilization when one types quickly (for no apparent reason, since it seems to do that even when "disabled").
An alternative is KeyRemap4MacBook which is much superior in terms of key remapping capabilities, but lacks a scripting language. (Personally however I have been able to do with it many of the things I did with AutoHotkey, so its worth exploring, though your mileage may vary)

Comment: @KevinColyar i like the design philosophy behind keymando, notices a vim and gmail flavor right away.  but it seems to be missing the crucial **abbr** / **iabbr** that would allow abbreviations to be used instead of being limited to single keyboard "chords"

Answer (score 6):

What is is you're trying to do?

[IronAHK](http://www.ironahk.net/) should work on a Mac - I'm not a Mac user so I've not tried it, but that would be my first choice for trying to get AutoHotkey scripts working.

[alternativeTo.net](http://alternativeto.net/) lists a few [Mac OS alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/autohotkey/?platform=mac) to AutoHotkey. The top result there is [Project SIKULI](http://sikuli.org/) which looks pretty similar to AHK in terms of features but with a different scripting language.

Comment: Hi Gary. I have an autohotkey script on my PC that boots chrome, waits for me to close it, then clears my DNS cache and then runs CCleaner in the background all in one click. Will IronAHK be able to do this? I will look into those alternatives that you listed thank you.

Comment: Project SIKULI seems to revolutionize UI scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Quicksilver can be a partial solution for some functionality of autohotkey: it has [shortcut key/trigger](http://leafraker.com/2007/09/17/how-to-create-a-quicksilver-trigger/) defining capabilities. For text expansion, mas os has [text expansion](http://lifehacker.com/5931337/do-yourself-a-favor-set-up-mountain-lions-built-in-text-expansion-with-these-shortcuts) built in.

On the other hand, applescript/automator is the mac os native solution for some automation tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/). Free to try, $20 to buy.

I haven't yet found an open source tool for Mac like AHK.

Answer (score 0):

I currently use [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) which is greati for key mappings, including chords of keys. It doesn't have a scripting language though. [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) seems a popular option with some scripting support (I have not tried it myself though).

Answer (score -1):

No one's mentioned [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/index.php) - free utility with tons of plugins for extendability.

Comment: How is it related to AutoHotKey and it's scripting capabilities?