# Simulating keyboard event through javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to simualte keyboard events in webpage through javascript since Actions is not supported in safari browser.

To Start with I created a simple form (given below) and trying to tab through the text boxes but it didn't work.

Java script used: (ubuntu and chrome browser). I fired the  script in the chrome browser console.

```
var pressTabKey = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
pressTabKey.initKeyboardEvent("keypress", true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 9, 0);
document.getElementById('1234').focus();
document.getElementById('1234').dispatchEvent(pressTabKey);
```

HTML Form:

```
   <html>      
   <head>         
   </head>   
   <body>
        <p>Test Page </p>      
        <form>
        <input  id="1234" type="text" value="Enter Here"> 
        <br>
        <br>
        <input  id="1235" type="text" value="Enter Here">           
        </form>  
  </body>   
  </html>
```

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript?

Comment: I did go through that thread and used those functions and parameters. But I couldn't simulate keyboard events like tabbing eventhough I could simulate mouse events. Anyway, I would checks those two blogs again.

Comment: Maybe this is of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events

Comment: When I tried the code you showed above - https://jsfiddle.net/pymgnbk9/2/ - it tabbed to the first input field as expected, so not sure what is wrong. Did you make sure the HTML loaded before calling the JS?

Comment: Sorry, why can't you just do the jumps with `focus()` ?
https://jsfiddle.net/pymgnbk9/3/

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Example:
I create an event and use dispatchEvent() to trigger it:

```
var pressTabKey = new Event('keydown');
document.getElementById('1234').addEventListener('keydown', function() { alert("hi!"); });
document.getElementById('1234').dispatchEvent(pressTabKey);
```

The function createEvent() is deprecated:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent

EDIT:
You could simply read the key code from a keydown or keypress event, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/adrielD/me9q1qu6/

HTML

```
<p>Test Page </p>      
<form>
    <input id="1234" type="text" value="Enter Here"><br>
    <input id="1235" type="text" value="Enter Here">          
</form>
```

JS:

```
var tab1 = document.getElementById("1234");
var tab2 = document.getElementById("1235");

tab1.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
     if(event.keyCode == 9) {
        event.preventDefault();
        tab2.focus();
     }
});

tab2.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 9) {
        event.preventDefault();
        tab1.focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to have jQuery loaded, you can do it like this:

```
$(el).trigger({type: 'keypress', which: 13, keyCode: 13});
```

Which for your example would be:

```
$("#1234").trigger({type: 'keypress', which: 9, keyCode: 9});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ for the full documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have met exactly the same problem, tried many things, and end up using [AHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to trigger the keyboard event (and some mouse events). I just cannot find any selenium-only solution. AHK is for Windows only, though. If you are using selenium on other platforms, like Mac OS, check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332254/autohotkey-alternative-for-mac-os-x).

With AHK, it is fairly easy to do a key press, after setting the focus, just start the AHK script, in which you 'send the key':

```
send, abc
```

AHK has a full-blown scripting language, so you can wrap this in a loop/conditional. You can also simulate mouse clicks at a specific position, if necessary.